# button in repeat under other repeat can't get data row

Tags: xpages, repeat, xpages-ssjs

I have a first repeat control that finds the name and pictures of the different types of products from the selected main product group.
In this first repeat control I have another repeat that finds every single article , stock and description for each product type of the first repeat. In this second repeat I have a button to order the specific article. 
The strange thing is in the label of the button I can put the article number, but in the onclick event I can't get the correct article number.
The data from the first repeat is comming from the domino server and is put in a viewscope array. The second repeat control get's it's data from an iseries server and is also put in an viewscope array, in order to put eveything into a table.
The code :

```
`<xp:repeat id="repeat3" rows="30" value="#{viewScope.lijst}"
            var="hoofdlijn" indexVar="index1">
            <xp:text escape="true" id="produktnaam">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:hoofdlijn[0];}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:text>
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:hoofdlijn[1];}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:text>
```

`
Then I have a computed field that is getting it's data from iseries for the given line and put's it's data into another viewscope array : "producten1"
Then comes the second repeat to display all the lines of this viewscope :

```
<xp:repeat id="repeat5" rows="30"
                    value="#{viewScope.producten1}" var="dezelijn2">
     <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField42">
       <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:dezelijn4[4];}]]></xp:this.value><!-- this works fine -->
     </xp:text><xp:button id="button3" styleClass="btn btn-xs btn-primary">

        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Bestel "+dezelijn4[0]}]]><!-- this gives the correct value for dezelijn4 -->
        </xp:this.value>

        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" execMode="partial" refreshId="menuPanel">
                <xp:this.action>
                  <![CDATA[#{javascript:if 
                      (sessionScope.containsKey[("besteld")]){
                      sessionScope.besteld.push ([dezelijn4[0],"1"]);
                      }
                  else {
                      sessionScope.besteld = new Array();
                      sessionScope.besteld.push ([dezelijn4[0],"1"]);
                       }
                }]]></xp:this.action><!-- gives a wrong value for dezelijn4 -->
      </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
 </xp:repeat>
 </xp:repeat>
```

The label of the button display's the article number (dezelijn4[0]) correctly.
The article number in the onclick event seems always to be the verry last article number of the very last product type.

How can I get the correct article number in my onclick event ?

Comment: Is this line correct `(sessionScope.containsKey[("besteld")])`?  I can't remember seeing that format before.  Can you try to just store any value e.g. a string not in an array?

Comment: This line is just to see if the sessionScope.besteld exists or contains data. If it already exists I just add data with the push. If it doesn't exist I create the sessionScope and then add the data with the push.

Answer (score 0):

In your second chunk of code your repeat var is dezelijn2 but the code within the repeat is referring to dezelijn4. Maybe it's a copy/paste error and you're referencing the wrong variable.

Comment: That's indeed a copy paste error. dezelijn4 is the correct var value. I'll change the code above accordingly.